# Rails Ajax Requests

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

Can anyone assist with this problem please.  I'm trying to do a AJAX request with Rails but keep on receiving this error message.

`ActionView::Template::Error (Missing partial client_sub_folders/_client_sub_folder with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:js, :html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:raw, :erb, :html, :builder, :ruby, :arb, :coffee, :jbuilder]}.`

Please see code below.  I'm simply trying to add to the list of items on the `show` page while staying on the same page without a page refresh. `client_sub_folders` is a nested resource within `client_folders` in case that makes a difference.  Thanks!

create.js.erb

```
$("#new_client_sub_folder").remove();
$("#new_collection").show();
$("#item_list").append("<%= j render(@client_sub_folder) %>");
```

client_sub_folder_controller.rb

```
  def create
    @client_sub_folder = @client_folder.client_sub_folders.new(client_sub_folder_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @client_sub_folder.save
        format.html { redirect_to client_folder_client_sub_folder_path(@client_folder, @client_sub_folder), notice: 'Client sub folder was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: client_folder_client_sub_folder_path(@client_folder, @client_sub_folder) }
        format.js {}
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @client_sub_folder.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        format.js {}
      end
    end
  end
```

new.js.erb

```
$("#new_collection").hide().after("<%= j render('form') %>");

_form.html.erb (for client_sub_folders)

    <%= form_for([@client_folder, @client_sub_folder], remote: true) do |f| %>
      <% if @client_sub_folder.errors.any? %>
        <div id="error_explanation">
          <h2><%= pluralize(@client_sub_folder.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this @client_sub_folder from being saved:</h2>

          <ul>
          <% @client_sub_folder.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
            <li><%= message %></li>
          <% end %>
          </ul>
        </div>
      <% end %>
      <%= f.label :room_name %>
      <%= f.text_field :room_name, required: true %>

      <div class="actions">
        <%= f.submit %>
      </div>
    <% end %>
```

show.html.erb (client_folders)

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>
        <h1> <%= @client_folder.client_name %> Collection </h1>

            <table>
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th colspan="3">Col A</th>
                  <th colspan="3">Col B</th>
                  <th colspan="3"> Col C </th>
                  <th colspan="3"> Col D </th>
                </tr>
              </thead>

                          <tbody>

              <%= render partial: "client_sub_folders/client_sub_folder" %>

          </tbody>
            </table>
            <%= link_to 'Create Client Collection', new_client_folder_client_sub_folder_path(@client_folder), class: "btn btn-success", id: "new_collection", remote: true %><br>


        <%= link_to 'Back to Client Folders', designer_client_folders_path(current_designer) %>
    </div>
</div>
```

**_client_sub_folder.html.erb**

```
<% @client_folder.client_sub_folders.each do |sub| %>
<tr id="item_list">
                    <td colspan="3"> <%= sub.room_name %> <%= link_to "(edit)", edit_client_folder_client_sub_folder_path(@client_folder, sub)  %> </td>
                    <td colspan="3"> <%= sub.images.count unless sub.images.nil? %> </td>
                    <td colspan="3"><%= link_to 'Add / Remove', client_folder_client_sub_folder_path(@client_folder, sub) %></td>
                    <td colspan="3"><%= link_to 'Delete Collection', client_folder_client_sub_folder_path(@client_folder, sub), method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
                  </tr><% end %>
```

Comment: May be this line has issue `format.json { render json: @client_sub_folder.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }` you pass request as json ?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to do this:

```
$("#item_list").append("<%= j render(@client_sub_folder) %>");
```

so the `render(@client_sub_folder)` needs a partial named `_client_sub_folder` in `client_sub_folders/_client_sub_folder` so that it can show the details directly.

In the partial `_client_sub_folder` you can put the code like this:

```
<tr>
   <td colspan="3"> <%= client_sub_folder.room_name %> <%= link_to "(edit)", edit_client_folder_client_sub_folder_path(client_sub_folder.client_folder, client_sub_folder)  %> </td>
   <td colspan="3"> <%= client_sub_folder.images.count unless sub.images.nil? %> </td>
   <td colspan="3"><%= link_to 'Add / Remove', client_folder_client_sub_folder_path(client_sub_folder.client_folder, client_sub_folder) %></td>
   <td colspan="3"><%= link_to 'Delete Collection', client_folder_client_sub_folder_path(client_sub_folder), method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
</tr>
```

And after creating the partial you can also change `show.html.erb` where you are doing this (looping on client sub folders and displaying the details):

```
<tbody id="item_list">
  <% @client_folder.client_sub_folders.each do |sub| %>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3"> <%= sub.room_name %> <%= link_to "(edit)", edit_client_folder_client_sub_folder_path(@client_folder, sub)  %> </td>
      <td colspan="3"> <%= sub.images.count unless sub.images.nil? %> </td>
      <td colspan="3"><%= link_to 'Add / Remove', client_folder_client_sub_folder_path(@client_folder, sub) %></td>
      <td colspan="3"><%= link_to 'Delete Collection', client_folder_client_sub_folder_path(sub), method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
</tbody>
```

You can change the above and do it like this:

```
<tbody id="item_list">
  <%= render partial: "client_sub_folder", collection: @client_folder.client_sub_folders %>
</tbody>
```

And after this your line of code:

```
$("#item_list").append("<%= j render(@client_sub_folder) %>");
```

will also work and not throw exception.

**More Details:** [PartialRenderer](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/PartialRenderer.html)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this @deep - The error is gone now but only problem now is the object is being submitted but I still have to refresh the page for the new object to appear.  Any thoughts on what I'm missing now?

Comment: Check your response if it is responding properly and rendering create.js.erb and if it is so then check what is it responding with, it is hard to say without looking into your new code.